# Displaying json on a table ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

How do I display the below code using ajax the problem is, I'm not able to display chequebook.statuses.name I just need to print name all data is fine but the name

ajax call is as below

```js
success: function(data) {

            $("#edit-error-bag").hide();

            $.each(data, function(i, chequeBook){ 
            var test = null;  
                 $.each(chequeBook.statuses , function(k , v ){ 
                           test = v[1]    
                 })

            $("#tbody").html("<tr><td>" + chequeBook.id + "</td><td>" + 
                chequeBook.account_id + "</td><td>" + chequeBook.number_of_books 
                 + "</td><td>" + chequeBook.number_of_leaves +   "</td><td>" +
                  ((chequeBook.currency_id == 1 ) ? 'USD' : 'USD') +  "</td><td>" +/*
                  ((chequeBook.statuses != 'undefined') ? 'Fine' : 'Not Fine' )*/
```

The content of json data

```
       {"error":false,"chequeBookRequest":{
    "id":50,10:42:56","account_id":46764995,
    "modifier_id":null,
    "statuses":{"id":4,"name":"Collected","description":"Cheque book is collected by a customer","created_at":"2020-02-18 10:27:05","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:27:05","deleted_at":null},
                            "modifiers":null}
                            }
```

Above code does not work I tried everything nothing seems to work from `ChequeBook.statuses.name` to `chequeBook[statuses][name]` to `chequeBook.statuses[0].name` to `chequeBook.statuses['name']` nothing works I just try to display the name of status not entire object.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, I checked for errors it returns "chequeBook.statuses is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response statuses are not an array. They are an object.

Your current attempts show that you are trying to access it like an array.

Assuming `chequeBook` is a variable that is referencing `chequeBookRequest` in your JSON response, then you can get the status name with `chequeBook.statuses.name`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have tried that approach still is not working it says "chequeBook.statuses is not defined" under errors

Comment: @konzlaugoko At the point you run the above code, what is the content of `chequeBook`?

Comment: All two comments  below are the content of chequeBook JSON 
{"error":false,"chequeBookRequest":{"id":50,"number_of_books":2,"number_of_leaves":3,"isVerified":0,"created_at":"2020-02-18 10:42:56","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:42:56","account_id":46764995,"currency_id":1,"user_id":3,"status_id":4,"modifier_id":null,"accounts":{"id":46764995,"account_type_id":1,"account_number":1781772881115,"amount":86.56,"limit":33779885,"currency_id":1,"overdraft_limit":1143055,"created_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:58","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:58","user_id":null,"account_status_id":2},

Comment: "currencies":{"id":1,"currency_name":"USD","currency_code":"USD","main_currency":1,"created_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:53","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:53","deleted_at":null},"statuses":{"id":4,"name":"Collected","description":"Cheque book is collected by a customer","created_at":"2020-02-18 10:27:05","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:27:05","deleted_at":null},"modifiers":null}}

Comment: @konzlaugoko Then you need to do chequeBook.chequeBookRequest.statuses.name

Comment: I still get "chequeBook.chequeBookRequst is undefined" When I do JSON.stringify(chequeBook) I got this data {"id":50,"number_of_books":2,"number_of_leaves":3,"isVerified":0,"created_at":"2020-02-18 10:42:56","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:42:56","account_id":46764995,"currency_id":1,"user_id":3,"status_id":4,"modifier_id":null,"accounts":{"id":46764995,"account_type_id":1,"account_number":1781772881115,"amount":86.56,"limit":33779885,"currency_id":1,"overdraft_limit":1143055,"created_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:58","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:58","user_id":null,"account_status_id":2},

Comment: "currencies":{"id":1,"currency_name":"USD","currency_code":"USD","main_currency":1,"created_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:53","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:26:53","deleted_at":null},"statuses":{"id":4,"name":"Collected","description":"Cheque book is collected by a customer","created_at":"2020-02-18 10:27:05","updated_at":"2020-02-18 10:27:05","deleted_at":null},"modifiers":null}

Comment: I have finally found a way out I will create the table in controller and return it as a string response to ajax where I will append it like so $('#table').append(data); now data is a whole table with contents formatted as string.